# how to use CURL to login site

Tags: c++, curl

I am very new to cURL, so hopefully could get some help. Currently, I am in a Window environment, and using Visual Studio.

I am trying to use cURL to access a DLink IP camera through the DLink website (https://mydlink.com/login). And grab the video stream by the IP camera to do some processing. But to do this, I have to first login. But I am not sure how to do it. 
Below is my code.

int main()
{
    CURL                *curl;
    CURLcode            result;
    char *url_1         = "https://mydlink.com/login";
    char *postdata      = "email=xyz@gmail.com&password=123456";
    char *cookiefile    = "tempcookie";

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if( curl )
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookiefile); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);      
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, dummy);   
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url_1);             
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postdata);   


        // Connect to target (login)
        result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if( result )
            cout << "Cannot connect to site, check your url!\n";
        else 
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

Could someone please enlighten me, or provide some piece of code for it? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1) Your example code is incomplete: you use dummy function which is not in your listing.
It is important that the dummy function returns size*nmemb (see manual for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION), so it is difficult to say what went wrong.

2) you don't output your error code: please use curl_easy_strerror to decode your error in the result, then you would know why it failed.

3) if I supply my own "dummy" callback, then I get an HTML page without errors, and the page itself does not complain about wrong password or anything (which is strange, but it kind of works).

Here is my dummy:

```
    size_t dummy(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
    {
      printf("%.*s", size*nmemb, ptr);
      return size*nmemb;
    }
```

I looked a bit further what mydlink.com is doing and it is doing acrobatics with the email address (like deciding if it is local, tries to guess a region etc), then manipulates cookies -- it is all in javascript, thus I am afraid one has to dig that Javascript in order to emulate proper login POST, or perhaps find some proper documentation about mydlink.com services, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, although I key in the wrong email or password, using curl_easy_strerror, it shows a “No Error”. Any idea why?

Comment: @wo_sugue What error would you expect? Do you get an error message (such as "403 - Forbidden") instead of a web page if you log in by hand?

Comment: @wo_sugue I think that you might be posting to a wrong address, i.e. the javascript on mydlink.com sometimes manipulates the "action" property of the form, like it sometimes sets to "/global" which means that the actual post might have to be done to a different URL.
I am not so good at debugging javascript, so it is too difficult for me to trace what is going on. In such cases I would snoop the network traffic to see what is the end result, but this one encrypts it into HTTPS stream and thus I don't know.

Comment: @wo_sugue notice that the form also has a hidden field "from" which is probably also handled by the script. My guess is that it is filled with region code (there are like a handful servers handling a different region). Consider contacting dlink or their forums.

Comment: Actually, I have another question. How can I make sure after I key in the Email and password, the details are sent? Do I need to write a line to ask cURL to click on the "Sign In"button? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: @molbdnilo, I did not get an error message even though I key in a wrong email or password. However, I do notice that if I key in the wrong email or password, the html will appear a line "Invalid
 e-mail and password combination".

Comment: @wo_sugue That web page has been received without any problems, so everything is fine from a HTTP point of view. That's why curl says "No Error".

Comment: @wo_sugue clicking the "Sign in" button only triggers the javascript which actually manipulates the form fields and submits. The problem is that curl is not doing this manipulation (it has no knowledge of the HTML forms and scripts). Ideally, you need to find out what is the end result of this javascript manipulation and emulate that in your C program. It might also include some tricks against cracking bots -- then it is going to be difficult if not impossible.